# Manually add new page in PDFBox using pdfbox-layout

Tags: pdfbox, pdfbox-layout

I'm using [pdfbox-layout](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout) to create and manage PDF documents using [Document](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/blob/master/src/main/java/rst/pdfbox/layout/elements/Document.java) API.

```
Document document = new Document();
```

It manages to create new page automatically if the text size increases beyond current page using [Paragraph](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/blob/master/src/main/java/rst/pdfbox/layout/elements/Paragraph.java) API.

```
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
```

However, I'm unable to add new page manually as and when needed. I want to print some content starting from new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the API's source code, I found that `add` method accepts parameter of type `Element`,

```
document.add(Element element)
```

And after inspecting all the classes that implements `Element` interface, I found the one that I need, i.e. [ControlElement](https://github.com/ralfstuckert/pdfbox-layout/blob/master/src/main/java/rst/pdfbox/layout/elements/ControlElement.java)

So, to add a new page, my code looks like,

```
document.add(ControlElement.NEWPAGE);
```